# Adding behaviours to control using code C#

Tags: c#, behavior

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and C# to create a Win Form application. I am trying to add mouse enter behaviour to a set of controls as follows;

```
int i = 0;
foreach(MetroTileItem item in game_tile_panel.Items){

        // THIS MESSAGE BOX DISPLAYS THE CORRECT VALUE
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

        item.MouseEnter += (Object sender, EventArgs e) => {
             // THIS MESSAGE BOX DOES NOT DISPLAY TO CORRECT VALUES
             MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        };

        i++;
}
```

The first message box returns the value of `i` for each item and displays correctly. The second message box, inside of the `MouseEnter` behaviour does not display the correct values for `i`, or atleast not the values I am expecting.

When I perform the `MouseEnter` behaviour at runtime the message box displays the value `3` for every item. Whereas I would expect the first item to display `0`, the second item `1` ect.

Can anyone shed should light on why this is happening and how I might fix it. Perhaps I am not able to add behaviours in this manner? Thanks

Comment: you can read about closures in more detail on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
foreach(MetroTileItem item in game_tile_panel.Items){

    int pickMe = i;    <<<<<<<<<<<<<

    // THIS MESSAGE BOX DISPLAYS THE CORRECT VALUE
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

    item.MouseEnter += (Object sender, EventArgs e) => {
         // THIS MESSAGE BOX DOES NOT DISPLAY TO CORRECT VALUES
         MessageBox.Show(pickMe.ToString());   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    };

    i++;
}
```

By declaring a new variable for each iteration the correct value gets captured. The fact that the event handler is not called until sometime(s) after the `foreach` is completed is why.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the [modified closure](https://kristofmattei.be/2013/04/26/foreach-now-captures-variables-access-to-modified-closure/) phenomenon: in short, the delegate you declare as the event handler captures the *variable* i, not the *current value* of i. This is called a closure. Therefore each event handler dereferences i with value 3 at the time that it's called because that's how you left i when the loop exited.

The blog post explains how to circumvent this using a local variable.